# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch - Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, soap

I am trying to deploy my server on heroku. I got this error:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

This is my Java class:

```
package introsde.document.endpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import introsde.assignment.soap.PeopleImpl;

public class PeoplePublisher {
public static String SERVER_URL = "http://localhost";
public static String PORT = "6902";
public static String BASE_URL = "/ws/people";

public static String getEndpointURL() {
    return SERVER_URL+":"+PORT+BASE_URL;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String endpointUrl = getEndpointURL();
    System.out.println("Starting People Service...");
    System.out.println("--> Published at = "+endpointUrl);
    Endpoint.publish(endpointUrl, new PeopleImpl());
}
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 52):

I had the same issue trying to create a minimal spring-boot application. I've compared heroku's java-getting-started implementation with mine and found this nice fix.
Just add this to **src/main/resources/application.properties**

```
server.port=${PORT:5000}
```

Comment: After hours of screaming and shouting, I found this post, and it saved my sanity. Thank you!

Comment: make sure not to use the port as 5000 as it is, better to use the port that your application uses by default e.g. 8080

Comment: I tried lots of solution final this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue with port binding. Then I found [this](http://nicholaspaulsmith.com/spring-boot-on-heroku/) awesome article where I understood how actually everything works when deploying on Heroku. After I read it I managed to solve my problem in 2 minutes.  The link has gone dead but find archived link [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180121111843/http://nicholaspaulsmith.com:80/spring-boot-on-heroku/).

Comment: That is indeed a great article. It solved my problem too, which is that for Tomcat, you need to add `-Dserver.port=$PORT` to your Procfile to get Tomcat to bind to the port Heroku specifies.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is dead.

Answer (score 7):

Simple solution:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/myapi-1.0.0.jar
```

Replace `myapi-1.0.0` with the name of your jar or use `*`

Note:
The order of the variables matter. For example: the following doesn't work.

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/myapi-1.0.0.jar
```

Comment: Actually the later worked for me. Any possible explaination? java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar

Comment: @nayak may be something changed over the years. My answer was valid in 2018.

Answer (score 5):

You must bind to the port that Heroku assigns you as the env var `$PORT`, and the host `0.0.0.0`. So you should change you code to include this:

```
public static String PORT = System.getenv("PORT");
```

The `SERVER_URL` part may be trickier. You could use 0.0.0.0, but if you truly need the publicly accessible URL, you'll need to set something like this (changing "yourappname" to your app name):

```
$ heroku config:set SERVER_URL="https://yourappname.herokuapp.com"
```

And then add the code:

```
public static String SERVER_URL = System.getenv("SERVER_URL");
```

Comment: Your advice about "0.0.0.0" host is golden. It helped me to start my server module at last :) Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Tried everything for myself. Answer by @fortellao was a lifesaver for me. Just a little addition if someone is using src/main/resources/**application.yml** like me:

```
app:
  server:
    port: {$PORT}
```

port: 5000 did the trick in my case.

Comment: app:
  server:
    port: ${PORT}

Answer (score 1):

Also, I would like to add that adding the following to Procfile, allowed me to deploy my Spring boot app to heroku and resolved the exception you described above:

`worker: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/myTargetJar-SNAPSHOT.jar`

None of the solutions, listed on the web, helped me to solve the problem, this is why I decided to post the solution which helped me here. Maybe it is not on time, though :)

Comment: I have changed 
"web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war" 
into 
"worker: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war" 
Run command on my computer 
"heroku local web" 
and got the message 
"[WARN] Required Key 'web' Does Not Exist in Procfile Definition"

Comment: You should also add a Procfile in the root of your project with the following content:
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/myTargetJar-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dserver.port=$PORT

Answer (score 1):

Since your this is not a Spring Boot app you should do something like this:

```
package introsde.document.endpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import introsde.assignment.soap.PeopleImpl;

public class PeoplePublisher {
public static String SERVER_URL = "http://localhost";
public String port;
public static String BASE_URL = "/ws/people";

public static String getEndpointURL() {
    return SERVER_URL+":"+port+BASE_URL;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    port = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);

    String endpointUrl = getEndpointURL();
    System.out.println("Starting People Service...");
    System.out.println("--> Published at = "+endpointUrl);
    Endpoint.publish(endpointUrl, new PeopleImpl());
}
}
```

And then on your Procfile:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/*.jar $PORT
```

This way you'll bind your socket to the port Heroku is expecting you to listen at.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are making request without wait the server finish run, so it break because cannot finish building before 90 seconds.

It's a guess that are happening here.

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurs when Heroku can not find the port specified in Procfile.

A simple solution to this problem is doing a port setting dynamically by Procfile.

Add in Procfile ->

`web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/nome_do_meu_app.jar`

Remember that the Maven packaging should be JAR.