# Java Webapp deployment to Heroku - Error > Error R10 (Boot timeout)

Tags: java, heroku, jersey, jetty

I am having a problem when deploying my webapp to Heroku platform as I am not able to make a REST call to the webapp. 
I've reviewed the logs, the following is returned:

```
2019-04-22T17:58:53.942100+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2019-04-22T17:58:53.942570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-04-22T17:58:54.082855+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-22T17:58:54.062137+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

I've done some research on this error and implemented different solutions ([one of the resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066878/error-r10-boot-timeout-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-second)) to resolve this but unable to do so. I've seen some resolution stating to implement the 0.0.0.0 as the host but in my code, I am not using any hosts and don't know where to implement one if I should.

Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // The port that we should run on can be set into an environment variable
        // Look for that variable and default to 8080 if it isn't there.
        String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
        if (webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
            webPort = "8080";
        }

        System.out.println("Webport in use: " + webPort);

        final Server server = new Server(Integer.valueOf(webPort));
        final WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();

        root.setContextPath("/");
        // Parent loader priority is a class loader setting that Jetty accepts.
        // By default Jetty will behave like most web containers in that it will
        // allow your application to replace non-server libraries that are part of the
        // container. Setting parent loader priority to true changes this behavior.
        // Read more here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/Jetty_Classloading
        root.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

        final String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
        root.setDescriptor(webappDirLocation + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
        root.setResourceBase(webappDirLocation);

        server.setHandler(root);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
```

Procfile -

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.example.heroku.Main
```

Also found this in the logs:

```
2019-04-22T17:57:23.846721+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=48973 -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.example.heroku.Main`
```

I've been following [Jersey Getting Started tutorial](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/getting-started.html). 
Any help is appreciated.